# Are there good references or books for multivariate (multi-response) generalized linear mixed model (MGLMM) in R?

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, references, multivariate-analysis

I did not find material on this topic. Information on linear mixed model (lmm) or generalized linear mixed model (glmm) is easy to find, but it is not not the case for multivariate (multi-response) generalized linear mixed model (MGLMM).

Can you recommend a good reference for multivariate (multi-response) generalized linear mixed models?

Answer (score 3):

One of the only books I can think of that cover this topic is the book *Multivariate Generalized Linear Mixed Models Using R*, which you can [find here.](https://www.routledge.com/Multivariate-Generalized-Linear-Mixed-Models-Using-R/Berridge-Crouchley/p/book/9781439813263)

[image]

I think the book speaks a while on the univariate case, so if you are just wanting to learn multivariate GLMMs, I would skip to Chapter 11 (Page 115), though you may miss some important information on the syntax for the main function they use for these models, `sabre`, so it may be good to at least familiarize yourself with the function first. I also believe there is a `sabre` coursebook that can also [be found here.](http://sabre.lancs.ac.uk/sabreR_coursebook5.pdf)

Comment: Thanks Shawn, I know the book and after your description I will have a look at it. I hoped to find something more recent, but arguably there are not many sources available

Comment: Something else you may be able to consider is a multi-level SEM, which allows you to include a GLMM framework into a SEM model (which of course allows multiple DVs).